# How to execute some function in CViewClass when I get a file with Openfile() in CDocumentClass?

Tags: c++, mfc

How to execute some function in `CViewClass`, when I get a file in `Openfile()` function in `CDocumentClass`?

I have a function `OpenFile` to get a file in `CDocumentClass`, and I can make it work getting a file and processing the file.

Now, I want to make some function in `CViewClass` operate after getting a file in CDocumentClass.

I've already tried to use `OnInitialUpdate()` in `CViewClass`, but it's executed only for the first time or the state of getting NEW project, so it doesn't make it work.

What function do I have to use to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

To reflect changes made to the Document in a view, you should call:

```
yourDoc->UpdateAllViews();
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eys41xfw.aspx) for more details.